# discord.py check if there is a mass join (raid)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I would like to have my bot check if more than 10 people enter in 15 seconds in a server with discord.py

Is there a default function of discord.py or do I have to create it myself?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find such a function! However making one is not so hard:

```
import time


...

THRESHOLD = 10
m = []
time_ = time.time()

def antiraid(member):
    global m
    global time_
    m.append(member)
    if time.time() - time_ >= 15.0:
        time_ = time.time()
        if len(m) >= THRESHOLD:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        m = []


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    bool_ = antiraid(member)
    print('Raid state: %s' % bool_)
```

Note: This is only an idea how to make this function! You can also implement this with threads which might be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # check if more than 10 people have joined in the past 5 minutes
    if members_joined_in_past_5_minutes > 10:
        # more than 10 have joined
        await bot.kick(member)
```

You will need to create the timer that resets the `members_joined_in_past_5_minutes` every 5 minutes.

```
import threading

def timer():
    While True:
        time.sleep(300)
        members_joined_in_past_5_minutes = 0
thread = threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=timer)
thread.start()
```